# Before unloading event doesn't display the custom message in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Returned the custom message as like in the code below for the beforeunload event but the dialog box contains the predefined message.  If the return statement is absent dialog box is not displayed.  It means we need to return some text. But that text is also not displaying in the dialog box.  Then why should we return some text?

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
                return "TESSTTTTTTTTTT";
});
```

Comment: you cannot return from the event handler. its an anonymous message and its getting lost. you may write `alert("TEST")` to check the same being executed.

Comment: This brief of code works for me, please show us more information, error code or more code

Comment: This is totally browser dependent. Many browsers don't accept the custom messages. Nothing you can do about that

Comment: If i didn't return anything alert box is not displayed.  In such case what should I return?